# How to create Python object graph (with circular dependencies) from text file

Tags: python, object

I have a text file that expresses objects and their interconnections, and I want to build the corresponding Python object structure, but I'm not sure what is the best way to handle circular dependencies.

To make this concrete, suppose I have a file:

```
a: b, c, other info for creating a
b: a, c, info...
c: a, d, info...
d: a, b, info...
```

I want to create objects A, B, C, D, where A.link1 = B, A.link2 = C and so forth. The problem is when I parse the first line, objects B and C don't exist, so I can't put them in A.

A few alternatives:

1. Read the file twice. Create the objects the first time, and build the links the second time. But reading twice seems ugly (and wouldn't work with stdin).
2. Create all the objects with text links. Then scan all the objects to replace the text links with object references.
3. Create a placeholder object if the target doesn't exist. Then fill in the placeholder when its line is read. But if I want to check for missing links, I'd need to make another pass.

I suspect there's a common Python idiom for doing this and I want to avoid overcomplicating things. Also, is it cleanest to have my object class handle this graph creation, or there should be a separate parser class?

(My objects are more complex than the stripped-down example, of course. Among other things, I plan to find connected components, if that makes a difference.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have class attribute `dicts` that maintain instances and links by label. Then you can implement `link1` and `link2` as properties:

```
class Node(object):
    links = {}
    registry = {}

    def __init__(self, label, *link_labels):
        self.label = label
        self.links[label] = list(link_labels)
        self.registry[label] = self

    @property
    def link1(self):
        try:
            return self.registry[self.links[self.label][0]]
        except (KeyError, IndexError):
            return None

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Node: ' + self.label

> a = Node('a', 'b', 'c')
> b = Node('b', 'a', 'c')
> c = Node('c', 'a', 'd')
> d = Node('d', 'a', 'b')

> print(a.link1)
> print(b.link1)
> print(c.link1)
> print(d.link1)

Node: b
Node: a
Node: a
Node: a
```